# Wordpress - User registration on a multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress multisite with two sites.

On the first site I have installed Gravity Forms and there I can use a hook after submission of the form to do some stuff.

On the second site I use the Exchange Membership Plugin from iThemes. If a user fills out the form on site 1 i want to create a members object on site 2.

Do you know any section within the wordpress codex how I can code this registration process? I have the hook of the gravity form, thats not a problem I assume but how can I add the user in the second site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you see "Multisite WordPress API" on the 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference page? It lists a variety of functions that do things to users on Multisite, e.g.:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_to_blog